# How to insert line break into excel using java?

Tags: java, excel

I am read from a database column which stores data like

testing\n
testing\n

I am then using the jxl.write.WritableWorkbook methods to generate the excel file that will read from this column.

However when being displyed as excel There are no line break in the column data.

What is the reason and how should i resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You might try: `WritableCellFormat.setWrap(true)`

Look here: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/

Answer (score 1):

I searched the internet since i needed an answer and here it is...

From JExcel API FAQ:

How do I add a newline or carriage-return to a Label cell?
Use **"\012"** or **"\n"**. Also make sure to turn on cell wrapping with `WritableCellFormat.setWrap(true)` or the newline will show up as a square (unknown character).

I tested it and it worked for **"\012"** or **"\n"** as i put also `.setWrap(true)` and i tested it with

```
WritableCellFormat times16format =
            new WritableCellFormat(times16font);
            times16format.setWrap(true);
            times16format.setAlignment(Alignment.RIGHT);
            times16format.setBorder(Border.ALL, BorderLineStyle.HAIR);


//Merge col[0-2] and row[0]
        sheet.mergeCells(0, 0, 2, 0);
        Label leftPartLabel =
                new Label(
                0,
                0,
                reportKingdomData + "\012" + dateData + " " + MyDateFormat.format(new Date()) + timeData + "\n" + MyTimeFormat.format(new Date()),
                times16format);

        sheet.addCell(leftPartLabel);
```

[Insert Line In jxl JExcel API](http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/insert-line-feed-within-an-excel-cell-417762.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 for (int row = 0; row<100; row++)
 {
  sheet.addCell(new Label(0,row,"Testing "+row);
 }
```

Feel comfortable to let me know, if you are facing problem and don't forget to mark/upvote correct answer.